# Unknown shower faucet part

Tags: plumbing, shower

[image]

I have a leaky shower faucet and was going to check the washer. What am I looking at here in the picture? Can't seem to get this cover off, it appears to be the actual control for the water flow and not the plastic cover, as seen on the other handles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the chrome inner sleeve from a knob that is now missing its external finned plastic portion.

If it is not pulling off easily (they pull directly off, just like a knob should...) then you may need to use a *faucet handle puller* to remove it.

Of course there are tricks-of-the-trade, like using penetrating oil and spraying up where the valve-stem splines meet the (probably corroded) sleeve spline and tapping (gently) around the outer part to get it to break away...

Comment: Gotta love the tricks of the trade... you can probably get a replacement handle from a plumbing supply company.

Comment: What is the use of three knobs?  I've only ever seen one, for combined hot+cold, or two, for separate hot/cold.  What is the third one for?

Comment: @John Gordon  Hot, cold and shower down spout/shower head.

Comment: @JACK Ah, I'm used to that being a small diverter.